# Does Tumblr use Knockout or some other JS Utility in their themes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, knockout.js, tumblr

I was just looking at Tumblr's page on how to create custom themes:
http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#pro_tips

And I noticed that they are using JS that is similar to Knockout or even Backbone am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of templating languages use this notation, or something similar, so I'd say, maybe, but probably not.

[Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/) springs to mind as something that uses a similar notation.

And though it's not identical, [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) also makes use of `{` and `}`.

Comment: But the templating language can be a Javascript language like Pure http://beebole.com/pure/ can it?

Comment: Yes, of course, but the syntax doesn't give much away – many templating engines use something like this.